# Non-ASCII filenames mangled in deployment package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

I deploy my VS2010 MVC3 project using "Build Deployment Package". The problem is that a couple of files have national (Swedish) characters ÅÄÖ in their filenames, and the deployment package gets these filenames wrong.

For example "Köpvillkor.pdf" becomes "K+Âpvillkor.pdf". The file has the right name in the unzipped "PackageTmp" folder, but inside the "<projname>-<version>.zip" file the filename is mangled, so it seems the problem lies in the way the package is zipped, i.e. it gets an UTF-8 encoded filename from the file system but stores it without conversion as ASCII or WIN1252 or some such inside the zip.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Are the filenames still mangled after you deploy the package to a remote site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found today that you can uncheck "Create deployment package as a zip file" and then zip it manually. I use WinZip to zip it manually, and the non-ASCII characters are correctly preserved.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS to import the deployment package zip file, the filenames will be converted back to the proper encoding.

Unfortunately Winzip, 7-zip and even Windows Explorer Zip extension don't understand the filenames encoding, manual deployment is not possible.